# React component content with JSX as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, function, jsx

I want to a get a React component's content with JSX as a string

```
const Component = () => <div>Hello</div>
console.log(Component.toString()) 
// desired result: "() => alert('hello')"
```

But I get some strange object instead

```
  "() => /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["jsxDEV"])("div", {
    children: "Hello"
  }, void 0, false, {
    fileName: _jsxFileName,
    lineNumber: 182,
    columnNumber: 26
  }, undefined)"
```

For example a basic function's content prints out normally

```
const func = () => alert('hello')
console.log(func.toString()) 
// result: "() => alert('hello')"
```

Any idea how to get a string representation of a React component?

Comment: In the first example, where is that `alert` coming from?

Comment: This is an impossible task because JSX does not exist at runtime - it is simply syntactic sugar that is transpiled into function calls.

Comment: What do you need it for? Depending on that there are different solutions available

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @R.Gurung, I am stupid & pasted wrong line, desired output to be `"() => <div>Hello</div>"`

Comment: @skyboyer, I need to show my component's content on a web page. Now I manually paste it as a string, but would be more convenient to get function's text right from the component itself.

Comment: still not sure if I understand you goal. Do you mean component's source code? you can, say, use [inline webpack loader configuration](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline) to load source code as a string. Also you can recursively process that `Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__['jsxdev'])` to build JSX markup from it(but it might be not _that_ accurate - say, it will include `React.forwardRef` or `React.memo` in the list)

Comment: do you want to print the html that will be displayed on the page or do you need the whole component with all the functions?

Comment: @Andrey, I want to print out whole component's code on a web page, like here, but here I do it manually by copy pasting https://antonarbus.com/post/gsap-in-react

Comment: I'm afraid that the effect you want to achieve is not easy. you can try doing something similar using [react-element-to-jsx-string](https://github.com/algolia/react-element-to-jsx-string)

Comment: @Andrey, thank you for the link, I checked it, but unfortunately it does not work as I wish. As you and Ian mentioned it seems not a trivial task to implement.